# How to return value from Observer?

Tags: angular, observable

I have the following function:

```
private getTranslateMenuItem(key: string): string {
      this.translate.get(key).subscribe((res: string) => {
        return res;
    });
  }
```

And I need that it return me sring data when I call this like:

```
let title = this.getTranslateMenuItem('pop');
```

Comment: Don't return the value, instead return the observable and allow the consumer to subscribe (next, error, complete) as necessary to set component properties, handle errors, etc.  If you need to use the value emitted in other observable actions operators such as switchMap or mergeMap can help achieve that.

Comment: Do you propose this: `private getTranslateMenuItem(key: string): Observable<string> {}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of attempting to return the value emitted by the observable, try simply returning the Observable and allow the consumer to utilize the emitted value, such as setting a class property:

**Service:**

```
public getTranslateMenuItem(key: string): Observable<string> {
  return this.translate.get(key);
}
```

**Component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '{{title}}'
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title: string;

  constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.someService.getTranslateMenuItem('foobar')
         .subscribe(
             value => this.title = value,
             error => console.log(error),
             complete => console.log('Completed');
         );
  }
}
```

This approach will you handle value, errors, and complete in the component and allow the service to just handle retrieving and processing/formatting values as needed.

Alternatively you can utilize the [async](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe in the component's template to subscribe/unsubscribe to the emitted values.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '{{title$ | async}}'
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.title$ = this.someService.getTranslateMenuItem('foobar');
  }
}
```

Hopefully that helps!